# New annotations break inspection of dataclasses

Tags: python, annotations, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

With PEP 563, `from __future__ import annotations` changes type annotations so that they are evaluated lazily, which provides a bunch of benefits like forward references.

However, this seems to play badly with other features, like dataclasses. For example, I have some code that inspects the type parameters of a class's `__init__` method. (The real use case is to provide a default serializer for the class, but that is not important here.)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import get_type_hints

class Foo:
    pass

@dataclass
class Bar:
    foo: Foo

print(get_type_hints(Bar.__init__))
```

In Python 3.6 and 3.7, this does what is expected; it prints `{'foo': <class '__main__.Foo'>, 'return': <class 'NoneType'>}`.

However, if in Python 3.7, I add `from __future__ import annotations`, then this fails with an error:

```
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

I think I understand why this is happening. The `__init__` method is defined in `dataclasses` which does not have the `Foo` object in its environment, and the `Foo` annotation is being passed to `dataclass` and attached to `__init__` as the string `"Foo"` rather than as the original object `Foo`, but `get_type_hints` for the new annotations only does a name lookup in the module where `__init__` is defined not where the annotation is defined.

I feel like I must be doing something wrong. I am surprised that these two new features play so poorly together. Is there a proper way to inspect the type hints of of an `__init__` method so that it works on dataclasses like it does on normal classes?

Comment: `get_type_hints(Bar)` seems to work normally, though it doesn't have a `return` annotation. It gives me `{'foo': <class '__main__.Foo'>}`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yeah, but `get_type_hints(Bar)` is not what I want. My use case is an inspection that takes a class and looks at the `__init__` method of the class. If `Bar` were not a dataclass, then `get_type_hints(Bar)` would not work. If a field of dataclass `Bar` was `init=False`, then it would not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [reported](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-September/155289.html) to the Python mailing list, this was [considered](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-September/155290.html) a "good catch" by the BDFL. According to the [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue34776), this has been fixed. The [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9518) for the fix was merged and backported. It works as expected starting in Python 3.7.6 and Python 3.8.1.

Comment: Do you think this may be related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937472/is-it-possible-to-test-a-function-that-uses-get-type-hints-with-a-doctest/55938392?noredirect=1#comment98530644_55938392 ?

Comment: @lovasoa They are probably related in that both `dataclasses` and `doctest` run code in a different scope from where it was defined, which creates corner cases for annotations.

Comment: The linked pull request has not yet been merged implying this is still broken in 3.7.4 (the latest release at the time of this comment).