# Is it possible to test a function that uses get_type_hints with a doctest?

Tags: python, annotations, doctest, type-hinting

I have a function that uses [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints). I want to add a [documentation test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) to it. However, it looks like get_type_hints fails to resolve types that are defined in a doctest.

Here is a simplified example:

```
import typing

def f(clazz):
    """
    >>> class MyClass:
    ...   my_field: 'MyClass'
    >>> f(MyClass)
    """
    typing.get_type_hints(clazz)
```

When running it with `python3 -m doctest test.py` it throws `NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get it to work in doctest, you would need to provide the correct evaluation scope.

Try this:

```
import typing

def f(clazz, globalns=None, localns=None):
    """
    >>> class MyClass:
    ...   my_field: 'MyClass'
    >>> f(MyClass, globals(), locals())
    """
    typing.get_type_hints(clazz, globalns, localns)
```

In doctest, a special set of values are used in the "eval scope" that happens with get_typing_hints.
It is looking for "test.MyClass" which doesn't actually exist otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import annotations

import typing


def f(clazz):
    """
    >>> test = 1
    >>> class MyClass:
    ...   my_field:'MyClass'
    >>> f(MyClass)
    """
    typing.get_type_hints(clazz)
```

add `from __future__ import annotations` at the beginning of the file, it work for me on python3.7

Comment: It works, indeed. Thank you ! Is this a bug in the typing module ?

Comment: I also still wonder why `my_field:'MyClass'` not work when it in doctest, it has different behavior when it in doctest and not. It seem the new syntax not yet ready when it in doctest.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the problem also exists with PEP563 annotations: https://gist.github.com/lovasoa/74ea62a89f5bf073b0e0c2f222008ae3